# How to set state to a PDAnnotationTextMarkup?

Tags: java, apache, pdfbox

I want to add a state to an annotation like the image below

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtEo7.jpg (Sorry i need at least 10 reputation to post images)

I try with this

```
PDAnnotationTextMarkup a= new PDAnnotationTextMarkup(PDAnnotationTextMarkup.SUB_TYPE_HIGHLIGHT);
a.getCOSObject().setString(COSName.STATE, "Completed");
```

But that does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the PDF specification ISO 32000-2:

> #### 12.5.6.3 Annotation states
>
> Beginning with PDF 1.5, annotations may have an author-specific state associated with them. The state is not specified in the annotation itself but in a separate text annotation that refers to the original annotation by means of its **IRT** ("in reply to") entry (see "Table 176 — Additional entries specific to a link annotation"). States shall be grouped into a number of state models, as shown in "Table 174 — Annotation states".
>
> State changes made by a user shall be indicated in a text annotation with the following entries:
>
> - The **T** entry (see "Table 172 — Additional entries in an annotation dictionary specific to markup annotations") shall specify the user.
> - The **IRT** entry (see "Table 176 — Additional entries specific to a link annotation") shall refer to the original annotation.
> - **State** and **StateModel** (see "Table 175 — Additional entries specific to a text annotation") shall update the state of the original annotation for the specified user.
>
> Additional state changes shall be made by adding text annotations in reply to the previous reply for a given user.

Table 174 — Annotation states — contains e.g. an entry in the state model "Review" for the state "Completed".

Thus, you have to set the state by adding a new text annotation in reply to the previous reply to the annotation (or, missing that, in reply to the annotation itself) with the state information.